# How to Print in Flex without the UI Components disappearing

Tags: apache-flex, printing, flex4.5

I'm printing from flex, and since I want to customise the jobs such as with margins and a title, I created a UI Component PrintTemplate. I add my stuff to the PrintTemplate and then I print it.

So the code is something like:

```
printTemplate.addElement(diagram);
addElement(printTemplate);

if (printJob.start()) {
  printJob.addObject(printTemplate);
  printJob.send()
}
```

The problem is that the UI components disappear from where they should be on the page when you add them to the printTemplate. This looks weird, even though you can add them back later. Is there a way around this - to stop them disappearing when I add them to the template?

Answer (score 2):

A component cannot be the child of two containers at the same time so there's no way you can show them in the original container.

You can, however, take a snapshot of the component you want to print and display it in a BitmapImage as the first child of that component. When printing is done, simply remove the BitmapImage.

```
    private function displaySnapshot():void
    {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new  BitmapData(_displayObject.width,_displayObject.height,false);
        bitmapData.draw(_displayObject,null,null,null,null,true);
        _snapshotImage = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
        _displayObject.addChildAt(_snapshotImage,0);
        _displayObject.visible = false; //optional
    }

    private function removeSnapshot(event:Event):void
    {
        EventDispatcher(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type,arguments.callee);
        _displayObject.parent.removeChild(_snapshotImage);
        _displayObject.visible = true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and I'll vote you up but it's not the answer I need. It's not just the display issue, it's also that I don't want to muck around removing and re-adding components back after printing into the correct position. Plus if I modify the components for printing, then i have to "un-modify" them again. If only I could copy them then none of this would be necessary. For some reason there is no problem when you add them directly with printJob.addObject(). I tried using your technique to make a bitmap and print that instead, but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: I never used printJob.addObject(), but my guess is that it takes a snapshop and print that instead, just like printJob.addPage(). Printing can get very tricky in Flex. If your component has no scrolling you can print the BitmapImage by scaling it before doing an addPage(_snapshotImage). If it has scrolling, then it will be clipped. You can remove clipping on the container itself but it will then be clipped by the app window. There's 2 alternatives then : scroll the component manually, take another snapshot, addPage, rinse and repeat or add it to a new, invisible window with no clipping.

Comment: By the way, I used the former technique to print an HTHLLoader. It was a pain, but in the end it works. It that case, I have done just what you said : "I modify the components for printing, then i have to "un-modify" them again". I have implemented an HTMLLoader printer class and use a static print(htmlLoader) function that does all the job.

Comment: Adobe explains their way of doing this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c80.html. It's probably the cleanest but typically code-heavy. I hate that kind of thing - creating another class for everything you want to print and then manually loading the properties up, painful.

Comment: This is bound to a component, just like I did. I'm pretty sure you can write one that should apply to most cases, but yeah, you get the idea. You COULD also clone everything you can to print if it's simple data, but this gets complicated pretty fast.